# ios Camera get date of photo taken

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, i have a custom camera class, so i can intercept the camera button's action.
I want to know exactly what time it was when the picture was taken. So when the camera button is pressed, i fetch the atomic time from the closest `ntp` server and call the `UIImagePickerController's` takePicture function.

When take a picture of the same atomic clock's time that i use in my function, i see that there's a difference between the time i fetched and the time it is on the atomic clock. 
I'm guessing this difference is exactly the time it takes for the camera to make the image.

This difference is even greater when the autofocus adjusts the image.

Is there a way to intercept the action when shutter is closed?

Comment: You are also dealing with latency of the network fetching the time.

Comment: that is corrected by the ntp library